# Get SPUser object

Tags: development

I am trying this code to get SPUser object but it keeps throwing exception of user not found even when it returns true for `DoesUserHavePermissions(...`, does anyone know any fix or way around ?

```
if (web.Site.RootWeb.DoesUserHavePermissions("UserLoginName", SPBasePermissions.Open))
{
   SPUser user = web.Site.RootWeb.Users["UserLoginName"];
}
```

Can't use `web.Ensure`

Answer (score 1):

Try `RootWeb.AllUsers` instead.

```
if (web.Site.RootWeb.DoesUserHavePermissions("UserLoginName", SPBasePermissions.Open))
{
   SPUser user = web.Site.RootWeb.AllUsers["UserLoginName"];
}
```

Or you can also try `RootWeb.SiteUsers`

[Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.siteusers.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

just created this console app for you:

```
        try
        {
            using (SPSite mysite = new SPSite("http://yourwebsite:2010"))
            {

                using (SPWeb web = mysite.OpenWeb())
                {
                    Console.Write("web users");
                    Console.WriteLine();
                    Console.WriteLine();
                    foreach (SPUser user in web.Users)
                    {
                        Console.Write(user.Name);
                        Console.WriteLine();
                    }

                    Console.WriteLine();
                    Console.WriteLine();
                    Console.Write("site collection users");
                    Console.WriteLine();
                    Console.WriteLine();
                    foreach (SPUser user in web.SiteUsers)
                    {
                        Console.Write(user.Name);
                        Console.WriteLine();
                    }
                }

            }
        }
        catch (Exception a)
        {
        }

        Console.Read();
```

so what you want is `web.SiteUsers` for **site** collection and `web.Users` for **webs** ;) not web.Site.RootWeb.Users. If you run the code above within a console app you should see the user within the list and if it has a domain tag or not!

or do:

```
using (SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Site.RootWeb) 
{
    SPUser user = web.Users["UserLoginName"];
}
```

get the correct web context if your looking for the root web of a site ;)